# How to get sorted itemssource from a datagrid

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have a grid with multiple columns and users can sort based on any column. Data, which is bound the grid is a collection of custom entity. I have a print button on the screen and  on click of this button I need to do a custom print. Print must show the data in the same order as displayed in the grid (with additional data)

Is there any way to directly get the sorted datasource instead of sorting the datasource in the sorting event?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. In WPF, always a `CollectionView` is bound, never the collection itself. If you don't specify a collection view yourself, a default one is used. You can access this default collection view like this:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(yourCollectionOfCustomEntities);
```

This is the collection view as shown by the grid with all the sorting and filtering applied.

Comment: Based on your answer what I have understood is that the source collection will never change and only the CollectionView will get changed (as and when user sorts data in any column). For my print to work I need data in the collection form (List(of Entities)). So the default collection view will not suffice. Is there an easy way to get the collection also sorted based on the sorted collectionView? One thing I observed while debugging is that the CollectionView has a protected property InternalList, which is having the sorted collection. But since the property is protected I can't get it.

Comment: When you enumerate over the collection view, the items should be returned in the sorted order... please check

Comment: Yes I am able to enumerate the collecion view and build the sorted collection.

Comment: @PankajVohra The right answer is given by Felipe below ... just use the Items property of the DataGrid.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the yourDataGrid.Items, Items reflect the currentview of the grid.
and you have to convert using the method Cast and after use .ToList();

imagine this

```
List<MyClass> myListOfMyClass = new List<MyClass>();
myGrid.ItemSource = myListOfMyClass;
List<MyClass> myListOfMyClassSortedByTheUser = myGrid.Items.Cast<MyClass>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just enumerate the Items property of your DataGrid. Unlike the ItemsSource property, the Items property appears to reflect exactly what's on the screen including sorting and filtering. For example:

```
foreach (var item in dataGrid.Items)
{
    // do something
}
```