# Persist sorting from DataGrid to ItemsSource collection

Tags: wpf, sorting, mvvm, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and I'm trying to do the Sort thing the most straightforward way: by clicking on the header of each column.

This is working great on the View (*in the MVVM context*), but I want to sort the underlying ViewModel collection (`ObservableCollection`) too. Any suggestions on how to implement the source collection?

Comment: Are you happy to ditch the DataGrid sorting altogether and rely on your underlying collection sorting instead? I'd think twice before doing that.

Comment: Here's the class, designed specifically to separate the actual data from the way it gets presented.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx

Comment: Nope, I am happy with the sorting it achieves on the View (that's the DataGrid's Items). I need the same sorting to propagate to the ItemsSource collection too.

Comment: than, it's more of question of how do you caputre 'SortingChangedEvent' - as the rest is pretty simple with Linq OrderBy/OrderByDescending calls. Am I right? One of the reasons why grid doesn't touch the underlying collection is it simply mightn't know how to sort it:) so it goes a thick way and sorts its itemns.

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333447/how-to-get-sorted-itemssource-from-a-datagrid

Comment: I did it here, it's a bit of overkill if you only need to have sorted actual collection, but you can get an idea how to implement it:

http://lucidsnippets.com/blog/dynamic-wpf-datagrid-columns-using-propertydescriptors/

Answer (score 1):

Bind the grid to a `ListCollectionView`, initialised with the `ObservableCollection`. The grid will use your pre-created `ICollectionView` instead of creating it's own `ICollectionView` based on your `ObservableCollection<T>` (which is the default behaviour),  and apply any sorting functionality/predicates to your instance.

As an added benefit, sorting/filtering that `ListCollectionView` will be reflected in your grid whenever you call MyListCollectionView.Refresh() from your ViewModel.

Once you've done this, iterating through the Items collection of your ListCollectionView will accurately reflect the current filter/sort state of your grid.