# Searching a DataGrid when it is sorted

Tags: c#, wpf, search, sorting, datagrid

I have implemented a simple search function that highlights a row in a DataGrid based on a search query. The gist of it is shown below:

```
public bool scrollToSearch(string query) {
    dataGrid.SelectedItems.Clear();

    for (; searchIndex < registrants.Count; searchIndex++) {
        foreach (string field in registrants[searchIndex]) {
            if (field.ToLower().Contains(query)) {
                dataGrid.SelectedItem = registrants[searchIndex];
                dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(registrants[searchIndex]);
                searchIndex++;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

It searches the list for a match, then highlights(selects) that row and scrolls it into view. The problem is that, when the DataGrid is sorted, the search will highlight a seemingly random row instead of the first result, because it is searching the original, unsorted list. Is there a way I can get at the sorted list to search it instead?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896422/persist-sorting-from-datagrid-to-itemssource-collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do this....

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(registrants);
```

then use `view` in place of `registrants` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Anurag's comment that the ListCollectionView is the right way to go. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx) for documentation on the ListCollectionView. The ListCollectionView creates another layer between your source and display which handles sorting, filtering and grouping. Bind your DataGrid to the ListCollectionView and use `SetCurrent()` to specify the selected item.