# Iterate over DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I iterate over a WPF DataGrid "as seen by the user" (e.g. the user might have sorted it or the user might have rearranged columns).

When I iterate using `ItemsSource`

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRowView dr in ResultDataGrid.ItemsSource)
{ .. }
```

then I am iterating over the original, unsorted DataGrid. Thank you for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get sorted itemssource from a datagrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333447/how-to-get-sorted-itemssource-from-a-datagrid)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your underlying collection reflects the visual collection.

So instead of relying on the `DataGrid` itself to do the sorting, for instance, sort the underlying `ObservableCollection` so that when you iterate through it, you are iterating in visual order.